# Does HTML5 canvas support browser-based zooming?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I had setup a simple canvas with a fillText drawn on it. It looks quite good, but when I use the browser provided zooming feature (Safari, Firefox), the antialiasing looks ugly.

I tried to use scale() raise the grid, but it doesn't help.

Is there any way to draw on a canvas that it looks sharp even with a zoomed browser window?

---

Screenshot (no zoom): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGWka.png

Screenshot (max zoom): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNPjF.png

Answer (score 23):

You can 'zoom' a canvas by scaling the canvas context prior to drawing commands to result in items drawn at a larger size, smoothly. For example, see [this example of mine](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html) that allows you to zoom way in on draw items and see details not available at the default presentation.

The problem with browser zooming is that the HTML5 canvas—like a JPG or PNG, and unlike SVG—is based on individual pixels. If you draw a circle in 10 pixels and then tell the browser to zoom it to 50 pixels the browser cannot "invent" data to draw a smooth circle. The best it can do is provide image interpolation to try to make the 'big pixels' look slightly smoother.

**The Solution**

With an image, you can take a picture with a lot of pixels (e.g. 1000x800) and tell the browser to display it at a different, smaller size (e.g. 250x200). When the browser zooms in, it *has* more pixels to display. For example:

```
<img src="1000x800.jpg" style="width:250px; height:200px">
```

You can do the same with a canvas. The number of pixels of *data* in the canvas are specified by the `height` and `width` attributes (in HTML or JavaScript). You can separately specify the CSS *display size* (like above) to a smaller size. You don't even need to modify your existing canvas drawing code; simply:

1. Adjust the `height` and `width` of your canvas by a particular factor (e.g. 4),
2. Use CSS to set the display height and width back to the original size, and then
3. Before all other drawing commands, scale up your context with `ctx.scale(4,4)`.

**Edit**: I have created an example of this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u5QPq/embedded/result/ ([code](http://jsfiddle.net/u5QPq/))

Here's what it looks like when you zoom in:
[image]

As an added bonus, your canvas will also *print* more smoothly (in case someone is into killing trees).

Comment: @st4rbuck You're welcome. Note that if this answer solved your question you should "accept" it: [click the large checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Phrogz: many thanks for this useful example. I am running into issue which might be related. Hope to guide me to find a solution. I use ng-signature-pad (based on canvas) to capture signature (scribble based). The problem, if the browser is not on 100% zoom, the drawing area is messed up, and when I upload an existing image (using `FileReader`) onto the canvas when the zoom is not 100%, the image looks funny or truncated. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: @tarekahf You should post this as a question, not as a comment on an answer for a (related, but different) question.

Comment: @Phrogz: I added the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514118/funny-behaviour-with-ng-signature-pad-canvas-used-to-capture-scribble-signatur). Hope there will be no down-votes!

Comment: This is not a good solution. It means you will be rendering at a higher resolution than necessary most of the time, and you have to choose an arbitrary upper limit to the zoom. DewiW's answer is much better.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, a `canvas` element will not automatically support browser-based zoom, i.e. as you zoom in, your canvas element will look ugly. Your browser simply can't draw detail that isn't there.

However, there are three things that happen when browser zoom is used on desktop:

1. The `window.devicePixelRatio` value changes to reflect the new physical-to-logical pixel ratio.
2. The reported width and height (`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`) changes in response.
3. The `onresize` event fires.

This means you can listen for the `onresize` event, and re-create your canvas in response to the new pixel ratio and display size. On desktop, this will give you a canvas element that is always sharp, without needing to draw the canvas element at a higher resolution than is required.

[codepen proof of concept](https://codepen.io/DewiWilliams/pen/MWKJRQq)

I've also written an article on Medium that goes in to more detail on this approach, and other techniques that can be used to make canvas elements more accessible to those with poor eyesight: [HTML canvas and accessibility](https://medium.com/@williamsdewi/html-canvas-and-accessibility-ffcfc317fab5)

Unfortunately, mobile/tablet pinch-zoom works slightly differently, and this approach does not work there. If anybody has an alternative approach that would work with pinch-zoom, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. As far as I understand, the drawing in this example is performed in the target zoom level (taking into account the `devicePixelRatio`), then transformed via CSS to a different size, and then the browser zooms this again to the target size. Is that correct? That would mean that there will always be scaling artifacts, since the canvas is scaled twice. Am I right?